# Calculate the bisection vector OM

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]
Calculate the bisection vector OM, by using the vectors that form an angle with it, $OA_1$ and $OA_2$

[image: The end formula]

I was thinking of using the Angle bisector theorem, but i can't seem to get that end formula look.

Comment: Do you  mean $M$ as the midpoint, or that the *angle* gets bisected?

Comment: From the "answer" it seems actually the question must have been about locating $M$ so that it cuts $A_1A_2$ in the ratio $K.$

Comment: M is not the midpoint by default, but if you let K = 1, it is. And the O angle gets bisected, yes.

Comment: If $A_1,A_2$ have different lengths and $K=1$ it will not give the bisection of the angle, only the midpoint (not the same points).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
\vec{OM}=\vec{OA_1}+\vec{A_1M}\\
\vec{OM}=\vec{OA_2}+\vec{A_2M}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{OM}=\vec{OA_1}+k\vec{MA_2}\\
\vec{OM}=\vec{OA_2}-\vec{MA_2}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{OM}=\vec{OA_1}+k\vec{MA_2}\\
k\vec{OM}=k\vec{OA_2}-k\vec{MA_2}
\end{cases}$$

Now , add two equations to obtain :

$$(1+k)\vec{OM}=\vec{OA_1}+k\vec{OA_2}$$

from which we have :

$$\vec{OM}=\frac{\vec{OA_1}+k\vec{OA_2}}{1+k}$$

Comment: Thanks, looks like i didn't know you could inverse the letters...